# Mongoose prevent next then() to be executed

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

With Mongoose I am saving a task to a `task` collection and if it goes well a board should be updated with the task data. However, I don't know how can I prevent executing the last `then()` (saving to the board) if there's an error on the previous one (saving the task).

I've been trying to use `Promise.reject()` but I am not sure how to return both `Promise.reject()` and the response status with an error.

```
// POST add a new task
taskRouter.post('/:boardId', (req, res) => {
  let task = new Task(req.body)
  let boardId = req.params.boardId
  let newTaskNumber
  let newTaskId

  // get lastTaskNumber from the board
  Board.findById(boardId)
    .select('lastTaskNumber')
    .exec()
    .then(board => {
      newTaskNumber = board.lastTaskNumber + increaseTaskNumberBy
      newTaskId = `${boardId}-${newTaskNumber}`
      task._id = newTaskId
      return
    })
    // save the task in the task collection
    .then(() => {
      return task.save(
        (err, task) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
              message: 'Error saving a task',
              error: err
            })
          } else {
            res.status(200).json(task)
          }
        },
        { _id: false }
      )
    })
    // *********
    //if the above fails, don't execute the next then() 
    // *********
    .catch(() => console.log('error saving a task'))
    // update lastTaskNumber in the board
    // add task to the 1st column of the board
    .then(() => {
      return Board.findByIdAndUpdate(boardId, {
        lastTaskNumber: newTaskNumber,
        $push: {
          'columns.0.tasks': {
            taskId: newTaskId,
            title: task.title,
            priority: task.priority
          }
        }
      })
    })
})
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do multiple documents operations. If doing these operations is dependent on one another you need to use mongodb transactions. Look at the docs for the same. https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/?_ga=2.209820949.1471563632.1557061335-729436005.1551899218

Comment: A bit confusing as written, and possibly incorrect, because there's an outer `task` and an inner `task`. Where you want `task.title` and `task.priority` it's not clear whether you expect these to be properties of the outer or the inner `task`. As written, it's the outer.

Comment: @cEeNiKc, I'm strugling with the need for a transaction here. Could you talk me through it please?

Comment: See mongodb provides atomicity for operating on a single document i.e if you are changing say like 4 fields of a single document, you can be ensured that all those changing will be saved or neither of them will be. But in your case you want to create a task and then if it was created without any error you want to update a document in different collection of Boards. For this use case you need to use mongodb transactions which will ensure either all the changes are saved or neither is. And if you can please use the new async await syntax with try catch block, it will make your code much better.

Comment: This is a very good blog post of using transactions with mongoose. Do look at this, it will make things more clear. https://thecodebarbarian.com/a-node-js-perspective-on-mongodb-4-transactions.html

Comment: There's no inner and outer task. I have a `task` collection with all the tasks possible, their `_id`, `title`, `priority`, and `desc` and other properties, and there's a second collection `boards` which keeps references to to `tasks`, and the information it needs about them, which is `_id`, `priority` and `title`.
When a task to a `task` collection is successfully added I want to add its correwpondence to the `board` collection.

Comment: Yeah. Don't get confused with inner task and outer task. Your use case requires mongodb transactions.

Comment: @Dandy, you have `let task = new Task(req.body)` (outer). Further down, you have an anonymous arrow function `(err, task) => {...}` (inner). Further down still, you read the properties `.title` and `.priority` of the outer `task`. That may be perfectly OK but it is possible that you intened to read the properties of the inner `task`. BTW: This isn't an answer to your question but I need to be sure I fully understand these two `task`s before I post an answer. It matters!

Comment: BTW: It's possible that you should employ a transaction as cEeNiKc suggests but its absense is not the cause of the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the second `task` was indeed a reference to the outer `task`. I've tried a solution with `async/await` and transactions, have still a few issues, I've updated my post.

Comment: @Dandy, can you point me to the documentation for `new Task()` please?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents

Comment: I've changed now model instance `save()` to model `create()` with an object inside of it, thanks to that I can use `session`. But still, transaction doesn't work.

Comment: I did it!!! Works perfect, thank you!! Not sure how should I post the answer with the code, because it's mostly @cEeNiKc suggestions that helped me.

Comment: @Dandy Glad to know you made it work

Answer (score 0):

```
    Board.findById(boardId)
        .select('lastTaskNumber')
        .exec()
        .then(board => {
             newTaskNumber = board.lastTaskNumber + increaseTaskNumberBy
             newTaskId = `${boardId}-${newTaskNumber}`  
             task._id = newTaskId 
             return
        }) // save the task in the task collection
       .then(() => { 
             return task.save( (err, task) => { 
                   if (err) { 
                        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Error saving a task', error: err }) 
                   }
                   return Board.findByIdAndUpdate(boardId, 
                   {
                        lastTaskNumber: newTaskNumber, 
                        $push: { 
                             'columns.0.tasks': {
                                  taskId: newTaskId,
                                  title: task.title, 
                                  priority: task.priority 
                              } 
                        } 
                   }) 
             }, 
             { _id: false } ) 
        })
       // *********
       //if the above fails, don't execute the next then()
      // ********* 
      .catch(() => console.log('error saving a task'))
```

The structure changed but this should do it

Comment: No, the `Board.findByIdAndUpdate()` is executed now no matter whether `task.save()` is successful or not, there's no condition at all.

Comment: I am starting to believe that I need a flag variable to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working example in mongoose with `async/await` and `transactions` as suggested in the comments.

The calls are being invoked in a sequence, the next one is being started after the previous one has been finished. By using transactions there's only one `catch` for all asynchronous functions. If one of the calls fail, all previous changes are being reverted from the database and the `catch` is being invoked.

```
taskRouter.post('/:boardId', (req, res) => {
  let task = new Task(req.body)
  let boardId = req.params.boardId
  let newTaskNumber
  let newTaskId

    // tslint:disable-next-line
  ;(async function addTask() {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession()
    session.startTransaction()

    try {
      await Board.findById(boardId, null, { session })
        .select('lastTaskNumber -_id')
        .exec()
        .then(board => {
          newTaskNumber = board.lastTaskNumber + increaseTaskNumberBy
          newTaskId = `${boardId}-${newTaskNumber}`
          task._id = newTaskId
        })

      await Task.create([task], { session }, null, {
        _id: false
      })

      await Board.findByIdAndUpdate(
        boardId,
        {
          lastTaskNumber: newTaskNumber,
          $push: {
            'columns.0.tasks': {
              taskId: newTaskId,
              title: task.title,
              priority: task.priority
            }
          }
        },
        { session }
      )

      await session.commitTransaction()
      session.endSession()
      return res.status(200).json(task)
    } catch (error) {
      await session.abortTransaction()
      session.endSession()
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Error saving a new task',
        error: error
      })
    }
  })()
})
```

Comment: Dandy, introduction of a transaction isn't what 's causing calls to be invoked in sequence. The sole reason for a transaction is to cause all "tranacted" database activity to be either accepted or rejected. Your use of a transaction may well be beneficial but it is not responsible for sequencing. You have answered your headline issue, prevention of next then() being executed, by rewriting the code using try/catch and async/await syntax (though one .then() has survived) and adopting a slightly different approach.  There is no reason why a tidied up version of your original code shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've described the async/await wrong in my comment, I updated it. I also don't know why my original idea was not working but either way transactions are much better solution than only promises.

Comment: There are two things wrong in your original code. (1) `task.save()` takes a nodeback and, in all probability, doesn't return Promise; it therefore doesn't contribute to the Promise chain - its asynchronism is a "side-shoot"  (2) your `.catch()`, in that position, needs to re-throw the error (or some other error) in order for the following `.then()` not to be executed. A better solution would be to move the `.catch()` to the end of the chain, or possibly keep it where it is and add another `.catch()` at the end of the chain, depending on how specific you want the reported error message to be.